# How do I add table to central widget in PyQt5 keeping my menu bar?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am having trouble creating a PyQt5 GUI where I want a table of information as the central widget and a menu bar (which I will eventually put sorting options into). My code allows me to have either the table OR the menu but not both, and can't set a central widget because the class is not defined. Hopefully it's just something small I'm missing. Would appreciate any help, thanks.

Here is my code:

```
class Main(QMainWindow):

def __init__(self,parent = None):
    super().__init__()
    #self.grid_widget = App(grid)
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):    


    exitAct = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'), '&Exit', self)        
    exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
    exitAct.setStatusTip('Exit application')
    exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

    self.statusBar()

    menubar = self.menuBar()
    fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
    fileMenu.addAction(exitAct)

    #self.setCentralWidget(self.grid_widget)

    self.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



class App(QWidget):

def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(App, self).__init__(parent)
    self.title = 'PyQt5 table'
    self.left = 90
    self.top = 90
    self.width = 800
    self.height = 600
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

    self.createTable()

    # Add layout, add table to grid layout
    grid = QGridLayout()

    grid.addWidget(self.tableWidget)

    self.setLayout(grid) 

    # Show widget
    self.show()

def createTable(self):
   # Create table
    self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(q1.index))
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(len(q1.columns))
    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(heads) #set column names to headers in df
    for i in range(len(q1.index)):
        for j in range(len(q1.columns)):
            self.tableWidget.setItem(i, j, QTableWidgetItem(str(q1.iat[i, j])))

    self.tableWidget.resizeColumnsToContents()
    self.tableWidget.resizeRowsToContents()
    self.tableWidget.move(0,0)

    # table selection change
    self.tableWidget.doubleClicked.connect(self.on_click)


@pyqtSlot()
def on_click(self):
    print("\n")
    for currentQTableWidgetItem in self.tableWidget.selectedItems():
        print(currentQTableWidgetItem.row(), currentQTableWidgetItem.column(), currentQTableWidgetItem.text())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Which produces this:

[image]

and ignores my whole tablewidget altogether.

I have commented out the 3rd line in the QMainWindow because it produces an error saying that App is not defined.

How do I set the central widget so that it allows the table to appear as well? Thanks.

Comment: what is `q1`???

Comment: q1 is the dataframe from the csv file on my computer.

Comment: see my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the application should only have a single main, to have several only the first one will be executed, and therefore everything that you are after will not be defined, and consequently App is not defined as you indicate.

So the solution is to eliminate the intermediate main and copy it to the final main.

```
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.grid_widget = App(self)
        self.initUI()
...

class App(QWidget):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, this has gotten rid of the App not defined error. Now it says that grid is not defined. Have I defined it incorrectly in the App class somewhere?

Comment: @shinobilou change `App(grid)` to `App(self)`, grid is not defined within the Main class, it also does not make sense to pass it as a parameter

Comment: I then realised that I had to change 
self.grid_widget = App(grid) to self.grid_widget = App(self). 
Hah. Thank you.